# Solr How to Populate mutlivalued field from a tokenstream in an analyzer?

Tags: search, solr, indexing, lucene, xsd

How to Populate mutlivalued field from a tokenstream in an analyzer?

I'm relatively new to solr. I understand that multivalued fields are populated before going into the analyzer. However, what I want to do is store particular words from the token stream as multivalued fields after passing through the analyzer.

For example:

I love to eat chicken bacon(token stream) ---> Analyzer ---> eat bacon(after filtering out other words) ---> (store in same but separate field tags) chicken, bacon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.

In fact, multivalued field after tokenizer is **one** collection of tokens just with appropriate gap offset to avoid overeager matching (that's what positionIncrementGap does).

On the other hand, try faceting on your target field. Facets operate on tokenized (rather than stored values), so you will get a breakdown count separately for chicken and for bacon.